# (Typescript) Generic parameter doesn't compile correctly for conditional type when boolean is used

Tags: typescript, boolean, conditional-types

I have the following type - when `P` is defined, the function should accept a parameter of type `P` and return value of type `P`. Otherwise, it should not take any parameters and 'return' `void`.
For some reason it doesn't work for boolean and:

1. I don't understand why.
2. Is there any way to make it work for boolean without explicitly adding additional condition when `P extends boolean` (as that works).

```
export type Test<P = void> = P extends void
    ? () => void
    : (payload: P) => P

const test0: Test = () => {} // compiles

const test1: Test<number> = (payload: number): number => payload // compiles

const test2: Test<boolean> = (payload: boolean): boolean => payload // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First **why**:

`boolean` is distributed as union of `true | false`, so resulting type is
`((payload: false) => false) | ((payload: true) => true)'`.

More info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22596#issuecomment-373722622)

---

How to make it work:

Only "naked types" are candidates for distribution. One of the possible ways to opt out:

```
type Test<P = void> = [P] extends [void] 
    ? () => void 
    : (payload: P) => P
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8AFKBeKA3A9gSwBMA%20DKAbRQF0oIAPYCAOwPnN0MoCgoeoB%20KAAoAlBhLsC3XgC4hYAIYgANjnkFZKUehIpOnAMY5GiKA0QAGWXBOYRYqAG8oAXygB6N1EMBbMHiUIeobGwKYIwACMVuFIjACu3gBGEABOJLYKyqrqUPFJqcKyeckp9pkqau6ePn4B8EFGJmbAAEzRiEiJODgB8ozpcooVOV09EH2FUKO9jGVD2VVeOL7%20CEA)