# TypeScript: Generic strange behaviour

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
export type Primitive = boolean|string;
export type ObjectItem = {[k: string]: ObjectItem|Primitive}; 
export type DynamicItem<T extends ObjectItem|Primitive> = T extends ObjectItem ? ObjectItemInterface<T> : PrimitiveItemInterface<T>;
export interface PrimitiveItemInterface<T extends (ObjectItem|Primitive)> {
    value(): T;

    set(v: T): void;
}

export interface ObjectItemInterface<T extends ObjectItem> extends PrimitiveItemInterface<T> {
    get<K extends keyof T>(k: K): DynamicItem<T[K]>;
}

const example: ObjectItemInterface<{
    enabled: boolean
}> = null;

example.get('enabled').set(true); //Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Why it thinks that there is `never` type?

I want it to see the boolean type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `boolean` as a *naked* parameter type, which makes it used as [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types), since `boolean` is `true|false`. You can see in:

```ts
let r = example.get('enabled');
// ^? r: PrimitiveItemInterface<false> | PrimitiveItemInterface<true>
r.set(true);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wza74m)

One standard trick/solution (see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038989/16466946)) is to make use of tuples: `[T] extends [ObjectItem]` instead of `T extends ObjectItem` to avoid the parameter being naked:

```ts
export type DynamicItem<T extends ObjectItem|Primitive> = [T] extends [ObjectItem] ? ObjectItemInterface<T> : PrimitiveItemInterface<T>;
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxaJbW) - see now that `r` has type `PrimitiveItemInterface<boolean>` which is what you originally expected.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of distributive behavior of `boolean`

[image]

solution is to stop the distributive behavior

`export type DynamicItem<T extends ObjectItem | Primitive> = [T] extends [ObjectItem] ? ObjectItemInterface<T> : PrimitiveItemInterface<T>;`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbTNMBuqAvHAEYQQA2wAhgHYA+AzjFvQOYDcAUKJLATJUAeTIArYAGMYASRjBscUgG8A2gGsAXHFbsOAXR1jJM+YsYYceQsAC+XOH3DR4SFHAAiierVxTzbAAeABU4UAV6ABNmOBNpOQVsSyxcfCIAPmU4NRCDcJBImJz4syT8gH44iQTA2XoFKAAzWilgUKydKzTbOobgZtb2kIzeflc4TH7BtvRUmyI+xpa20IKi2IAKUsSLboXgAEoslR44c7gCWioAV2BNw50Q3jOL5mAYTYInx8uITCivDsPGcAngU2WQ2qpl22HqkNWYQiwGisR2gSyyNRc2s6WASwGK2GJ1e5w4HyCAGl1ijihpgIgIE04CNNto4JTft5fP5AqE1JSDKMeMCeFIIPRWAU-GAaMYamVFPDCUMgqcLuFfGQaFEdBRqHR6CKsqR6DcqFQXqAZTQAHTkz4AchRtG1wCijsOtvenzYd0OXCAA)

//========Extra==========

but the weird thing, the type should be `any` not `never`

[image]

//=======Update=========

I found the explanation why OP got never, explanation I quote from discord:

> when you declare a type, the inferred parameter types on the function
> do not override so v can be any in the function literal (because
> typescript is refusing to infer from the union type A) but when you
> call a, typescript does the true & false = never and refuses to allow
> you call `a`

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUSAeAuKAzAhgGwGcIBKBAPigFcA7Aa2oHsB3a0gH2TU2ACdKTyVOoxbEAUGIDGDagWBQc6OPCQA3YvDIBvAL5iA9PqjGTpgHoB+CRJxIAjMSA)